# Is there an excel function that can reference data depending on data validation input?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created an excel sheet (Sheet 1) database listing client a-z with their respective emails in columns A and B respectively.

On a different sheet (Sheet 2), I have referenced a  column with data validation, such that in Column A of Sheet 2, I need to select client a,b,c,...,z. Is there a way possible on excel such that Column B of Sheet 2 automatically looks and returns the correct data for the specified client's email by referencing the database that has been created in Sheet 1?

Thank you.

[Database example (Sheet 1), with client's names and email addresses in Columns A and B respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqAW2.png)

[In Cell A2 (Sheet 2), I have selected Client 'Adam'. Is there a way Cell B2 returns 'Adam's' email automatically by referencing database (Sheet 1)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz6cB.png)

Thank you

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`, `INDEX/MATCH`, `FILTER()` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of one.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Database Example'!B:C,2,0)
=INDEX('Database Example'!C:C,MATCH(A2,'Database Example'!B:B,0))
=FILTER('Database Example'!C:C,'Database Example'!B:B=A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have VLOOKUP formula, it should help. In B2 you need to write

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Database example'!B:C,2,0)
```

and then copy and paste it to the cells below (range from B3 to B7).